# If$f=u+iv$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)|}{|h|}$ exist then either $f$ or $\overline f=u-iv$ have derivative at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continuous and have continuous first partial derivative at $z_0 =x_0+iy_0$. If$f=u+iv$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)|}{|h|}$ exist then either $f$ or $\overline f=u-iv$ have derivative at $z_0$

Here is what I got

$u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continuous and have continuous first partial derivative at $z_0 =x_0+iy_0$ meaning

$$u_x(z_0)=v_y(z_0)$$
$$u_y (z_0)=-v_x(z_0)$$

Let $h=a+ib$, then

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)|}{|h|}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(x_0+a+i(y_0+b))-f(x_0+iy_0)|}{|a+ib|}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|u(x_0+a,y_0+b)+iv(x_0+a,y_0+b)-u(x_0,y_0)-iv(x_0,y_0)|}{|a+ib|}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|u(x_0+a,y_0+b)-u(x_0,y_0)+i[v(x_0+a,y_0+b)-v(x_0,y_0)]|}{|a+ib|}$$

Now I will break them up a little bit

$u(x_0+a,y_0+b)-u(x_0,y_0)=u(x_0+a,y_0+b)-u(x_0,y_0+b)+u(x_0,y_0+b)-u(x_0,y_0)$

From here how do I get to $u_x(x_0,y_0)+u_y(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: It's easier with the Wirtinger calculus. Do you know what the Wirtinger derivatives are?

Comment: I'm not sure, can you show me some example of it, I may know it but don't know its name.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}$ are the Wirtinger derivatives. If you know these, and how to work with them, that is usually way more convenient than working with the partial derivatives. The Cauchy-Riemann equations become $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$.

Comment: The first notation look familiar to me but the second one doesn't, I guess I haven't learnt about these yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's remind ourselves of some real limits.
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u(x+h,y) - u(x,y)}{h} = u_x(x,y)
$$
and
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u(x,y+h) - u(x,y)}{h} = u_y(x,y).
$$
Let $h = h_1 + ih_2$. Consider $u(x_0+h_1,y_0 +h_2) - u(x_0,y_0)$. We can write this as
$$
u(x_0+h_1,y_0 +h_2) -u(x_0+h_1,y_0)+ u(x_0+h_1,y_0)- u(x_0,y_0)\tag{1}
$$
Now 
$$
\lim_{h_2\to 0}\frac{u(x_0+h_1,y_0 +h_2) -u(x_0+h_1,y_0)}{h_2} =u_y(x_0+h_1,y_0)
$$
and we have similarly setup for the other piece in $(1)$. Let's multiple through by $h_i$ so $u(x_0+h_1,y_0 +h_2) -u(x_0+h_1,y_0)=h_2u_y(x_0+h_1,y_0)$ and we can write $(1)$ as
$$
h_2u_y(x_0+h_1,y_0)+h_1u_x(x_0,y_0)
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u_x(x_0+h_1,y_0+h_2)-u_x(x_0,y_0)}{h_1+ih_2}
$$
Let $n,m\in\mathbb{R}$ and set $h_1 = n$ and $h_2=nm$.
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u_x(x_0+h_1,y_0+h_2)-u_x(x_0,y_0)}{h_1+ih_2} = \frac{n(mu_y+u_x)}{n(1+im)}
$$
We can do the same for the continuous function $v(x,y)$.
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\biggr\lvert\frac{f(x_0+h_1,y_0+h_2)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}\biggl\rvert=
\biggl\lvert\frac{mu_y+u_x+imv_y+iv_x}{1+im}\biggr\rvert
$$
Let the limit be $A$. Then squaring, we have
\begin{align}
A^2 &= \biggl\lvert\frac{mu_y+u_x+imv_y+iv_x}{1+im}\biggr\rvert^2\\
&= \frac{(mu_y+u_x)^2+(mv_y+v_x)^2}{1+m^2}\\
0 &= m^2(u_y^2+v_y^2-A^2)+2m(u_xu_y+v_xv_y)+(u_x^2+v_x^2-A^2)
\end{align}
Let $m=1$. Then
\begin{align}
2(u_xu_y+v_xv_y) &=0\\
u_xu_y+v_xv_y &=0\tag{2}\\
u_y^2+v_y^2-A^2 &=u_x^2+v_x^2-A^2\\
u_y^2+v_y^2 &=u_x^2+v_x^2\tag{3}
\end{align}
Now consider $(u_x+iu_y)^2=u_x^2-u_y^2+2iu_xu_y$ and $(v_x-iv_y)^2=v_x^2-v_y^2-2iv_xv_y$. Setting the real and imaginary parts equal and rearranging, we get
$$
(u_x+iu_y)^2=u_x^2-u_y^2+2iu_xu_y=v_x^2-v_y^2-2iv_xv_y=(v_x-iv_y)^2\\
u_x^2+v_x^2=u_y^2+v_y^2\\
u_xu_y+v_xv_y =0
$$
That is, $(2)$ and $(3)$ correspond to $(u_x+iu_y)^2=(v_x-iv_y)^2$ so either $f$ or $\bar{f}$ satisfies the CR conditions and have a derivative at $z_0$.

Comment: I have a questionquestion: you set $h_1=n$ and $h_2 =nm$ implies that $h_2/h_1 =m$. How do you know this?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif it is like you setting $h=a+bi$. I picked those since the $n$ would cancel in the derivation and leave me with only $m$.

Comment: It is not like setting $h=a+bi$ and letting $a$ and $b$ tend to zero independently. Choosing $h_1=n$ and $h_2 =nm$ you let h tend to zero following a line, so you didn't prove the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: Suppose $a,b\in \mathbb C$ and $|a+be^{-2it}|$ is constant for $t\in [0,\pi].$ Then one of $a,b$ must be $0.$

Proof: If both $a,b$ are nonzero, then $a+be^{-2it}$ traces out a circle of positive radius whose center is not the origin. The points on such a circle cannot have constant modulus, contradiction. Thus one of $a,b$ must be $0.$

To our problem: WLOG, $z_0=0.$ Let $A=f_x(0), B=f_y(0).$ Then

$$\tag 1 f(z) = f(0) + Ax + By + o(z)$$

as $z= x+iy \to 0.$ Now $x=(z+\bar z)/2, y =(z-\bar z)/(2i).$ Thus $(1)$ takes the form

$$ f(z) = f(0) + \frac{A-iB}{2}z + \frac{A+iB}{2}\bar z + o(z).$$

Therefore

$$ \frac{f(z) -f(0) }{z} = \frac{A-iB}{2} + \frac{A+iB}{2}\cdot \frac{\bar z}{z} + o(1).$$

We are given that the absolute value of the left side has a limit $L$ as $z\to 0.$ Hence so does the right hand side. Now for any fixed $t$ we can let $z = re^{it},$ with $r\to 0^+.$ On the right we conclude

$$L =\left |\frac{A-iB}{2} + \frac{A+iB}{2}\cdot e^{-2it}\right |.$$

Since this is true for any real $t$ we see by the lemma that either $A-iB = 0$ or $A+iB=0.$ Now check that $A-iB=0$ says precisely that the Cauchy Riemann equations for $f$ are satisfied at $0,$ hence $f'(0)$ exists. Similarly $A+iB=0$ happens iff the Cauchy Riemann equations for $\bar f$ are satisfied at $0,$ hence $(\bar f)'(0)$ exists. We're done.